# How to reset content of the developer portal

Tags: azure-api-management

The Azure APIM developer portal (new one) has been edited and now some of the menues dont work.

**Is it possible reset the content ?**

I have tried the capture.bat (from another APIM instance) and generate.bat into the broken instance but it didnt appear to work - i even made changes to one of the jpg files in the scripts.v3/media directory but it didnt get changed in the portal when i ran generate.

I find the "run your own hosted developer portal" scenario confusing. I am unclear on:

- where is the content held for the unpublished managed portal ?
- where is the content held for the published managed portal ?
- where is the content held for the unpublished "own hosted" portal ?

  - ie when running locally (npm start on the Github repo code)
- where is the content held for the published "own hosted" portal ?

When developing on a self hosted scenario, ideally i think it would be benefitial to hold the content locally so that it could be placed in source control. Failing that, is it possible to customise such that the "run your own hosted developer portal"  content is in an accessible location such as a blob in a container on the same storage account that the code is being published to? That way I could copy content from an unbroken APIM into a storage account and develop with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible reset the content ?

Yes. Have you actually tried the simplest solution?

1. Open developer portal in edit mode:

[image: edit mode]

2. Click reset content

[image: click reset content]

---

> where is the content held for the unpublished managed portal ?

> where is the content held for the published managed portal ?

Same place - in the APIM resources. When you edit developer portal and you save it,
other users won't see those changes until you click publish.

You can also use developer portal revisions, from [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2021-01-01-preview/portal-revision) or directly from Azure Portal. This will give you an opportunity to go back to previous revisions. So if you are publishing manually, after you edit and save developer portal I recommend to go to the revisions tab in azure portal and publish it from there - this way you will have simple version control.

For managed version, important thing to understand is, "content" consists of:

- content types and content items which are just json template files describing your pages on developer portal. Those can be accessed by REST API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2021-01-01-preview/content-type) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2021-01-01-preview/content-item) (this is a parent child relation).
- and your uploaded custom media (images, fonts etc.) that can be retrieved from APIM Blob Storage. To get SAS URL for APIM Blob Storage and connect to it, just call your APIM Management API with address `POST /portalSettings/mediaContent/listSecrets/` - this URL is not documented but you can call it like any other endpoint.

And that's it. That's all you need - json file and media files. The rest is managed for you. And in fact that's what those scripts from [github repository](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/tree/f5f94b945bc5374edb5ba3034526e094483449ef/scripts.v3) are doing. `capture.bat` for example is downloading all the media and json from developer portal and saves it to your local folder. So you can for example save it to source control or/and upload to another APIM developer portal instance.

---

When managed developer portal and online editor is not enough for you and you need more customization, like custom widgets etc., you can go with self hosted version. It gives you more freedom but the downside of course is you are responsible for its upgrades.

> where is the content held for the unpublished "own hosted" portal ? ie
> when running locally (npm start on the Github repo code)

When you run `npm start` it just runs locally like when you develop any other webpage. In this case it uses `webpack-dev-server` to host the page.

> where is the content held for the published "own hosted" portal ?

Wherever you feel like it. That's the idea behind the self-hosted version. After you are happy with the changes you've made, just run `npm run publish` and files will appear in `dist` folder. Then you can upload them to the resource of your choice. [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-self-host) shows you how to enable hosting of static websites for your blob storage and host your developer portal there. Everything is explained, just follow the article carefully step by step (don't skip any step, every single one is important in order to successfully configure and deploy your self-hosted developer portal). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2584295/steppingrazor

The one point i would take issue with is the unpublished "own hosted" content - when i change content from my own locally running instance I cannot see any content changes when i do "git status" - this makes me think that even when running from "npm start" the content is being accessed from the APIM content

Answer (score 0):

Now we can Reset Azure APIM Developer Portal using Azure DevOps Extension. [Reset Azure APIM Developer Portal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Celezant.azure-apim-cleanup)

This Extension Resets the Developer Portal to Default Contoso Version removing all the Pages, Layouts, and Contents from the Developer Portal Permanently. It cannot be restored back to the previous version once implemented.